# KO: how to subscribe to UI updated for post-processing?

Tags: knockout.js

In my page, I have a drop down (select) and then a table, both of which are bound to the view model.  When I change the drop down the table refreshes with the data associated with that item in the select.

I want to do some UI processing on the table after it is populated.  I tried subscribing to the drop down selection (which does get fired and my function called) but the table data is updated after the subscribe completes.

What I want to do is update the table background row colors using a simple function like so:

```
updateRowBgColors = function (tableId) {
    $("#" + tableId + " tr:gt(0):odd").css("background-color", "#f7f7f7");
    $("#" + tableId + " tr:gt(0):even").css("background-color", "#fff");
};
```

Yes, I know I can set a class for alternating rows in the data-binding in html, but that wouldn't answer my question about why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the afterRender binding along with your [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html):

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: people, afterRender: doYourThing}">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Number"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in your view model:

```
self.doYourThing = function(insertedDomElementArray, dataItem) {
    $('tr:odd').css("background-color", "#f7f7f7");
    $('tr:even').css("background-color", "#fff");
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/SrfSt/2/)